# How to disable sorting in an Excel shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to allow only the owner of a shared excel workbook to be able to sort data on the file. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: This is going to be difficult to do in a way that no one could get around. You cannot protect a sheet or use VBA code on a shared workbook. 

You could temporarily remove the sharing option by going into Review / Share workbook and then unticking the allow other users... option, then sharing again after adding the protection. However, after having a quick experiment I could not get the protection to work in a way that it prevented sorting without disabling other functionality (but this is probably possible with some fiddling).

Comment: Also bear in mind that sheet protection passwords can be hacked very easily: http://www.theofficeexperts.com/VBASamples/Excel02.htm

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is an in-office file that does not require too much security and I am the owner of the file. I have no problem temporarily disabling the sharing in order to add some VBA code. Can you provide some more details as to what you did and what code did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main reason for this is not robust security, but the accidental resort that happens in a workbook shared with others this should work in the Worksheet_Activate event

This is not even attempting to hide the sorting prohibition

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim WhoCanSort As String
  WhoCanSort = ThisWorkbook.WriteReservedBy
   If WhoCanSort = "Charlie" Then
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Else:
     ActiveSheet.Protect AllowSorting:=False
   End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach that doesn't require a macro.  If you use the "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" feature, you can keep the cells locked and the worksheet protected for most users, but define ranges of cells that can be edited by a particular user.  See this article: http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/10/01/kb-sorting-locked-cells-in-protected-worksheets/